# how to replace a cell in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

After forming the below python pandas dataframe (for example)

```
import pandas

data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
```

If I iterate through it, I get

```
In [62]: for i in df.itertuples():
    ...:     print( i.Index, i.Name, i.Age )
    ...:     
0 Alex 10
1 Bob 12
2 Clarke 13
```

What I would like to achieve is to replace the value of a particular cell

```
In [67]: for i in df.itertuples():
    ...:     if i.Name == "Alex": 
    ...:         df.at[i.Index, 'Age'] = 100 
    ...:
```

Which seems to work

```
In [64]: df
Out[64]: 
     Name  Age
0    Alex  100
1     Bob  12
2  Clarke  13
```

The problem is that when using a larger different dataset, and do:

First, I create a new column named like **NETELEMENT** with a default value of `""`
I would like to replace the default value `""` with the string that the function `lookup_netelement` returns

```
df['NETELEMENT']    = ""
for i in df.itertuples():
            df.at[i.Index, 'NETELEMENT'] = lookup_netelement(i.PEER_SRC_IP)
            print( i, lookup_netelement(i.PEER_SRC_IP) )
```

But what I get as a result is:

```
Pandas(Index=769, SRC_AS='', DST_AS='', COMMS='', SRC_COMMS=nan, AS_PATH='', SRC_AS_PATH=nan, PREF='', SRC_PREF='0', MED='0', SRC_MED='0', PEER_SRC_AS='0', PEER_DST_AS='', PEER_SRC_IP='x.x.x.x', PEER_DST_IP='', IN_IFACE='', OUT_IFACE='', PROTOCOL='udp', TOS='0', BPS=35200.0, SRC_PREFIX='', DST_PREFIX='', NETELEMENT='', IN_IFNAME='', OUT_IFNAME='') routerX
```

meaning that it should be:
`NETELEMENT='routerX'` instead of `NETELEMENT=''`

Could you please advise what I am doing wrong ?

**EDIT**: for reasons of completeness the `lookup_netelement` is defined as

```
def lookup_netelement(ipaddr):
    try:
        x = LOOKUP['conn'].hget('ipaddr;{}'.format(ipaddr), 'dev') or b""
    except:
        logger.error('looking up `ipaddr` for netelement caused `{}`'.format(repr(e)), exc_info=True)
        x = b""
    x = x.decode("utf-8")
    return x
```

Comment: Is your example wrong? Do you mean `if i.Name == "Alex": `?

Comment: indeed, thanks. copy-paste error :)

Comment: What is `lookup_netelement ` ?

Comment: is a function that retrieves a value stored in a redis key

Comment: Are you trying to apply the function i.e `df['new'] = df['PEER_SRC_IP'].apply(lookup_netelement)`

Comment: yes, that did the trick! thanks!

Comment: Glad can help I added that to answer do vote and accept if it was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you are looking for where for conditional replacement i.e

```
def wow(x):    
    return x ** 10

df['new'] = df['Age'].where(~(df['Name'] == 'Alex'),wow(df['Age']))
```

Output :

```
      Name  Age           new
0    Alex   10   10000000000
1     Bob   12            12
2  Clarke   13            13
3    Alex   15  576650390625
```

Based on your edit your trying to apply the function i.e

```
df['new'] = df['PEER_SRC_IP'].apply(lookup_netelement)
```

Edit : For your comment on sending two columns, use lambda with axis 1 i.e

```
def wow(x,y):    
    return '{} {}'.format(x,y)

df.apply(lambda x : wow(x['Name'],x['Age']),1)
```

Comment: thanks @Bharath but the operation has to be an on-a-per-cell-based operation, not column-wise

Comment: My guess is you are not looking for replacement.

Comment: thanks @Bharath. BTW, can you please advise how this can be generalised with two parameters, for example

Comment: `df['IN_IFNAME']     = df[ ['NETELEMENT', 'IN_IFACE'] ].apply(lookup_iface)`

Comment: where `lookup_iface` takes 2 arguments: `lookup_iface(dev, ifidx)`

Comment: yes, but how this could be achieved using the specific dataframe ?

Comment: I updated my solution hope that gives you some insights